# Is there a way to reorder the y axis values in decreasing order while keeping the x axis values the same in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of numeric data that corresponds with specific dates and I would like to make a line chart showing the changes. When I enter my code, I end up with a graph that is not ordered on the y axis so the numbers are all over the place. I would like the graph to range from 0-15 with the values associated with the dates just as points.

```
ggplot(TomFrostDO, aes(TomFrostDO$Date, TomFrostDO$Surface)) +
  geom_point(aes(x= TomFrostDO$Date, y=TomFrostDO$Surface), color="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=TomFrostDO$Surface, color="red"))
```

[image: image of data]

Comment: Can you use `dput` to share a chunk of your dataset in your question? I can think of a couple of possible issues here, but I can't test those ideas without knowing the exact structure of your data frame (e.g., what type are those columns?).

Answer (score 1):

I will try my luck (if I'm wrong I will delete this post) ... did you get this kind of graph ? 
[image]

If so, it is because your `surface` data are not numerical values (I bet that when you open your file in R, it gets these values converted as factor). You can access this by doing:

```r
> str(data)
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ surface: Factor w/ 13 levels "0.69","1.9","2.05",..: 6 5 2 3 7 13 1 12 4 8 ...
 $ Date   : Date, format: "2019-05-29" "2019-06-10" "2019-07-08" "2019-07-11" ...
```

To solve this issue, you can transform your variable in numeric by doing:

```r
data$surface = as.numeric(as.vector(data$surface))

> str(data)
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ surface: num  6.66 5.31 1.9 2.05 6.72 ...
 $ Date   : Date, format: "2019-05-29" "2019-06-10" "2019-07-08" "2019-07-11" ...
```

And now, if you are plotting these values, you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes( x = Date, y = surface))+
  geom_point(color = "red")+
  geom_line(color = "red")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", 
               date_labels = "%b%y")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15), breaks = c(0,5,10,15))
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

If not, can you please add a reproducible example of your dataset and also an image of the current plot you are getting.

BTW, when you are writing an expression for `ggplot(...`, you do not need to specify `$` in your `aes`, because as you defined `data` in the first part, `ggplot` knows where to look for column names. 
So simply as `ggplot(data = data, aes( x = Date, y = surface)` is enough. So, no need to repeat it in the `geom_point` or the `geom_line` because they will be made based on what you passed in `ggplot(...`. 
You can have the use to pass these kind of arguments in `geom_` if you need to plot particular data that you did not define in the first `ggplot(..` (for example, such as a second dataset to use, or a second y axis ...)

**Data**

```r
data = data.frame(surface  = c(6.66,5.31,1.90,2.05,6.72,13.65,0.69,12.80,3.83,7.57,9.33,11.63,9.82),
                  Date = as.Date(c("29/05/2019","10/06/2019","08/07/2019","11/07/2019","22/07/2019","5/08/2019",
                                 "19/08/2019","22/08/2019","04/09/2019","16/09/2019","30/09/2019","14/10/2019","14/11/2019"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was what I was missing.